How to download from arn:aws
I am trying to download the file stated in https://www.javacodegeeks.com/processing-real-time-data-with-storm-kafka-and-elasticsearch-part-1.html.
From the tutorial above, the data can be downloaded from https://history.adsbexchange.com/downloads/samples/.  However when I open it in the browser, it shows:
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:977233880211:loadbalancer/app/v2-adsbx-prod-vpc-a-ingress-alb/7666043f80e660c4

I am not sure how to download the file given the link above.  Need your advise where to begin at.

That article is about 3.5 years old and it's likely things have changed.  There isn't a way to download from an ARN.  I'd contact the author of the article or "ADS-B Exchange".
